# Find the latest file by modified date

Tags: command-line, find

**If I want to find the latest file (mtime) in a (big) directory containing subdirectories, how would I do it?**

Lots of posts I've found suggest some variation of `ls -lt | head` (amusingly, many suggest `ls -ltr | tail` which is the same but less efficient) which is fine unless you have subdirectories (I do).

Then again, you could

```
find . -type f -exec ls -lt \{\} \+ | head
```

which will definitely do the trick for as many files as can be specified by one command, i.e. if you have a **big** directory, `-exec...\+` will issue separate commands; therefore each group will be sorted by `ls` within itself but not over the total set; the head will therefore pick up the lastest entry of the first batch.

Any answers?

Comment: btw, you do not need none of all those backslashes.

Comment: @enzotib: you do (**\+**), otherwise you get `find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Comment: @arrange: I don't have this error, as `+` has no meaning for `bash`, so no need to escape it.

Comment: @enzotib: you're right, my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You do not need to recur to external commands (as `ls`) because `find` can do all you need through the `-printf` action:

```
find /path -printf '%T+ %p\n' | sort -r | head
```

Comment: Yeah, I came up with `find . -type f  -exec stat --format=%y \{\} \+ | sort -r | head -n1` but your solution is far cleaner!

Comment: Append `| cut -d ' ' -f2` to get filename only

Comment: You can also cull the output of `head` to include a certain number of lines. I only needed the first line, so I used `head -n 1`

Comment: @qwr wrote "Append | `cut -d ' ' -f2` to get filename only".  

Thanks! Although better append `| cut -d ' ' -f2 -` to avoid problems with filenames that contain spaces.

Comment: ... and if you want the list sorted from oldest to latest (at the bottom) `sort | tail`

Comment: ... and if you only want to see files (not directories) use `find . -type f`

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem today, but I attacked it without `find`.  I needed something short I could run over `ssh` to return the most recently edited file in my home directory.  This is roughly what I came up with:

```
ls -tp | grep -v /$ | head -1
```

The `-p` option to `ls` adds a trailing slash to directories, the `grep -v` removes lines ending in a slash (aka, all directories), and the `head -1` limits the output to a single file.

This is much less verbose than using `find` if all you want to return is the file name.

Comment: This doesn't handle subdirectories.

Answer (score 4):

This is on my system faster than `printf`, though I don't understand why

```
find /path -type f -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} + | sort -r | head
```

Comment: I confirm, is faster.

Comment: One more point, `...  | sort -r | head -n1 | cut -d " " -f 4-` if you want to get the filename only.

Comment: I just found `sort -r` will wrong if filename across multiple lines exist.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: I guess this post is not 'not particularly useful' as I thought it was. This is a really fast solution that just keeps track of the most recently modified file (instead of sorting the entire list of files):

`find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | awk 'BEGIN { mostrecenttime = 0; mostrecentline = "nothing"; } { if ($1 > mostrecenttime) { mostrecenttime = $1; mostrecentline = $0; } } END { print mostrecentline; }' | cut -f2- -d ' '`

Spread over multiple lines for clarity it looks as follows:

```
find . -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | awk '
    BEGIN { mostrecenttime = 0; mostrecentline = "nothing"; }
    {
        if ($1 > mostrecenttime)
            { mostrecenttime = $1; mostrecentline = $0; }
    }
    END { print mostrecentline; }' | cut -f2- -d ' '
```

End of EDIT

---

Not a particularly useful post but since 'arrange' was discussing speed, I thought I'd share this.

arrange's and enzotib's solutions involve listing all files inside the directory with their mtimes and then sorting. As you know sorting is not necessary to find the maximum. Finding maximum can be done in linear time but sorting takes n log(n) time [I know the difference isn't much, but still ;)]. I can't think of a neat way of implementing this. [EDIT: A neat (albeit dirty looking) and fast implementation provided above.]

Next best thing - To find the most recently edited file in a directory, recursively find the most recently edited file in each level 1 subdirectory. Let this file represent the subdirectory. Now sort the level 1 files along with the representatives of the level 1 subdirectories. If the number of number of level 1 files and sub-dirs of each directory is nearly a constant, then this process should scale linearly with total number of files.

This is what I came up with to implement this:

```
findrecent() { { find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} + | sort -r | head -1 && find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec findrecent {} \;; } | sort -r | head -1; }
findrecent .
```

I ran this and got a bunch of `find: findrecent: No such file or directory` errors. Reason: -exec of find runs in a different shell. I tried defining findrecent in .bashrc, .xsessionrc but these didn't help [I'd appreciate help here]. In the end I resorted to putting

```
#!/bin/bash
{ find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} + | sort -r | head -1 && find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec findrecent {} \;; } | sort -r | head -1;
```

in a script called `findrecent` in my PATH and then running it.

I ran this, kept waiting and waiting with no output. Just to be sure I wasn't dealing with any infinite loops I modified the file to

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$1" >&2
{ find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec stat -c "%y %n" {} + | sort -r | head -1 && find "$1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec findrecent {} \;; } | sort -r | head -1;
```

and tried again. It did work - but took 1 minute 35 seconds on my homefolder - arrange's and enzotib's solutions took 1.69, 1.95 seconds respectively!

So much for O(n)'s superiority over O(n log (n))! Damn you function call overhead! [Or rather script call overhead]

But this script does scale better than the earlier solutions and I bet it'll run faster than them on google's memory bank ;D

Comment: This is the only answer that actually works correctly for me. The other answers produced some files that weren't actually the most recent. Thank you, almost 8 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Use `perl` in conjonctin with `find` :

```
 find my_directory -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\n' | perl -ane '@m=@F if ($F[0]>$m[0]); END{print $m[1];}'
```

You get the name of the file with the greatest epoch == last file modified.

Answer (score 1):

It's not nearly as fashionable, but it's also possible to achieve this with **Midnight Commander**: search for *, panelize the result, sort by  modification time in reverse order.

Obviously, it's a bit slower than `find` - my home directory, containing 922000 files, was sorted by `mc` in almost 14 minutes while `find` spent less than 5 - but there are some benefits:

- I'd probably spend longer then the 9 minutes difference inventing a proper find invocation :)
- less chance of an error (forgot to specify -r for sort etc. - start again)
- it's possible to play with the result set by changing sort order etc. - without re-querying the files.
- possible to perform file operations only on *some* files from the result set - i.e. sort by size, delete a few large files which are not needed