# Sort files in directory by creation date (Birth)

Tags: bash, filesystem, stat

In my `Downloads` folder I have a lot of files. I need to arrange them according to the following criteria:

- they shall be arranged by type;
- files of the same type shall be listed one after the other by creation date, or alternatively according to the date I put them to my `Downloads` folder.

Please take a look: [Find the latest file by modified date](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61179/find-the-latest-file-by-modified-date)

Example: in my `Downloads` directory I have `*.tar.gz`, `*.pdf`, `*.zip` files. When I go to my `Downloads` directory I want to see my `*.tar.gz` files arranged together and sorted by the time I added them to this directory. I expect that the fifth `*.tar.gz` file is the fifth youngest in terms of birth time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My previous answer was began with this wrong statement:

*Linux does not store file creation time*

Yes - Linux kernel does not provide API to get creation time stamps from file system.

But as it is written in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) ext4 provide file creation timestamps:

> ext4 also adds support for date-created timestamps. But, as Theodore
>   Ts'o points out, while it is easy to add an extra creation-date field
>   in the inode (thus technically enabling support for date-created
>   timestamps in ext4), it is more difficult to modify or add the
>   necessary system calls, like stat() (which would probably require a
>   new version) and the various libraries that depend on them (like
>   glibc).

Also [as answered in unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time)

```
Several file systems store the file creation time, 
although there is no standard name for this field:

   - ufs2  → st_birthtime
   - zfs   → crtime
   - ext4  → crtime
   - btrfs → otime
   - jfs   → di_otime
```

---

Here is great [question/answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470134/how-to-find-the-creation-time-of-a-directory) how to find file creation stamp. Script written by @terdon:

```
get_crtime() {

    for target in "${@}"; do
        inode=$(ls -di "${target}" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
        fs=$(df  --output=source "${target}"  | tail -1)
        crtime=$(sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${inode}"'>' "${fs}" 2>/dev/null | 
        grep -oP 'crtime.*--\s*\K.*')
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "${target}" "${crtime}"
    done
}
```

Add this script to your .bashrc.

Now using this script you can get what you want.

Go to folder which content you want to sort

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
$ get_crtime * | sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f1,3,4,6 | sort -k2M -k3,4n
```

For `tar.gz` files

```
$ get_crtime *.tar.gz | sed -r 's/\s+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f1,3,4,6 | sort -k2M -k3,4n
```

---

**Sources**

- [How to find creation date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91197/how-to-find-creation-date-of-file)
- [Where I found script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/470134/how-to-find-the-creation-time-of-a-directory)
- [What file systems on Linux store the creation time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7562/what-file-systems-on-linux-store-the-creation-time)
- [Wiki ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4)
- [Understanding ext4 timestamps](http://digital-forensics.sans.org/blog/2011/03/14/digital-forensics-understanding-ext4-part-2-timestamps)

Comment: " last modification time" not modify but birth time

Comment: @alex as i write before, linux does not store filr creation date. or by telling "birth" you mean smth else?

Comment: @alex I found solution