# Find files from timestamps

Tags: command-line, bash, find

I have a lot of files, of which I need to show only those created in the last 3 hours, and sort this list by date. I tried to do it with the following command:

```
find /root/shell/copy/ \( -type f -mmin +180 \) | get_crtime | xargs ls -t | head -1
```

`get_crtime` is a function created for `.bashrc` as shown [in this example](https://askubuntu.com/a/443599/1575742) to find out the date of creation for a file.

How can I use the command correctly?

[image]

Comment: What is the end goal? Are you sure you want *creation time* rather than *modification time*?

Comment: @steeldriver my end goal is to upload files created in more than 3 hours, and from the resulting list to sort by the newest, it is the creation date that interests me

Comment: But *why* do you believe that you need creation time? It's not widely used in Linux, and your `find -mmin` is going to return files based on modification time anyhow.