# How do I create timestamped backups for certain files I edit?

Tags: bash, scripts, backup

**x11**, not Wayland

I often edit a variety of plain text files such as .css, .mkd, .sh, and .txt as well as *.odt* and *.ods* files.

All my files have

- [safe characters](https://pclosmag.com/html/Issues/201607/page03.html) limited to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`
- no spaces in them
- and have appropriate extensions.

Geany 1.32 comes with a customizable plugin to automatically save a timestamped backup to a destination of the user's choice. For example, a timestamped backup of *~/.bashrc* looks like this:

```
/home/dkb/Public/GeanyBackups/.bashrc.2019-08-28-16-25-51
```

[image: Geany allows timestamped backups]

Gedit offered [something similar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/double-save-gedit/downloads) years ago. Regaining this function *may* still be possible using the Manage External Tools… plugin. Answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1168156/248158) illustrate usage of this plugin.

As far as I know, other plain text editors such as *featherpad*, *kate*, *leafpad* and *mousepad* don't have such a feature. Even LibreOffice saves just one backup (if enabled in *Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Load/Save*).

It's possible to use *rsync* to backup files to timestamped folders but I want to capture backups of rather frequent edits in a destination of my choice.

I would like to have a script that allows me to perform a conventional save and immediately thereafter to generate a timestamped backup of a limited class of files I edit in my various text editors or in LibreOffice. I'd bind this script to a keyboard shortcut while leaving the conventional shortcuts still available.

Comment: Would be quite easy to create a tiny process that would create a time-stamped backup on every instance a file is saved or changed on disk, but you probably want to limit the number of max backups?

Comment: It's by signal, not by polling, zero on resources, how else are you imagining it if it is not from within the application in question? Haven't been out for a day :), but I myself have been here as an unnoticed background process :)

Comment: You should really look at a version management system such as Git.

Comment: @JacobVlijm, re. the number of backups, I don't mind removing older ones manually.

Answer (score 2):

#### Automatic time-stamped backups of a (any) specific file

If you are not afraid of compiling a `vala` file, the snippet below can be used. The advantage is that it is signal-based (using `FileMonitor`) and resource-consumption is zero. Furthermore, you don't need an extra manual action.

*How it works*

- Just run the executable with the watched file and the targeted directory (to save the backups to) as arguments, e.g.

  ```
  '/home/jacob/Desktop/watch_out' '/home/jacob/Desktop/test' '/home/jacob/Desktop'
  ```

  Each time the file `test` is saved (so changed) on disk, a backup like:

  ```
  2019-08-29_09-14-26_test
  ```

  will be created.

  ***N.B just keep it running, it will automatically create the backups (!)***

#### The code

```
/*
this snippet will watch a specific file (args[1]) for changes, make a time-
stamped copy into a set directory (args[2]). The advantage is that any file
can be watched, independent to the application it is edited with.
have fun!
Jacob Vlijm
*/

namespace watchout {

    File watched;
    string watched_fname;
    string watched_fpath;
    string target_fpath;

    public static void main(string[] args) {
        string watched_file = args[1];
        target_fpath = args[2];
        watched = File.new_for_path(watched_file);
        string[] fdata = getnamedata(watched_file);
        watched_fpath = fdata[0];
        watched_fname = fdata[1];
        MainLoop loop = new MainLoop();
        try {
            FileMonitor monitor = watched.monitor(FileMonitorFlags.NONE, null);
            monitor.changed.connect(dosomething);
            loop.run();
        }
        catch (Error e) {
        }
    }

    private string[] getnamedata (string watched_file) {
        string[] watched_data = watched_file.split("/");
        int len_data = watched_data.length;
        string path = string.joinv("/", watched_data[0:len_data - 1]);
        string fname = watched_data[len_data - 1];
        return {path, fname};
    }

    private void dosomething(
        File file, File? otherfile, FileMonitorEvent event
    ) {
        // event types:  https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.FileMonitorEvent.html
        if (event == FileMonitorEvent.CHANGES_DONE_HINT) {
            makebackup();
        }
    }

    private void makebackup () {
        var now = new DateTime.now_local();
        string datestring = now.format("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S");
        string targetstring = target_fpath.concat("/", datestring, "_", watched_fname);
        File target = File.new_for_path(targetstring);
        try {
            watched.copy (target, 0, null, () => {
            });
        } catch (Error e) {
            print ("Error: %s\n", e.message);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Setup

1. Install `valac`(to be able to compile)

   ```
   sudo apt install valac
   ```
2. Copy the snippet above into an empty file, save is as `watchout.vala`
3. Compile it with:

   ```
   valac --pkg gio-2.0 /path/to/watchout.vala
   ```
4. Run it as described in *How it works*

Comment: Yes, but if I want to edit another file, I'll then have to enter a command for that as well? Also, instead of `watch_out`, I had to use `watchout`.

Comment: @DKBose your question was about a single or a few specific files as I understand it. Anything is possible of course, a directory, a set of files etc. As it is, it indeed is meant for a defined file, not a dir. Multiple instances can be called of course.

Comment: In my question I have "I often edit a variety of plain text files such as .css, .mkd, .sh, and .txt as well as .odt and .ods files." So I do want a solution applicable for various files located anywhere in my home folder, in ~/Documents, ~/Dropbox, ~/.themes, etc. Of course, I won't be editing them all at the same time. Your solution is perfect if I'm editing (and saving) just the one file repeatedly in a session.

Comment: Suggestion: make directory and put symlink to files  you want to backup periodically. Jacob can edit his code to backup everything in that specific directory with no problems

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following script, *timestamp.sh*, and assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to run it.

```
#!/bin/bash

xgg="$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)"

if [[ "$xgg" == *" - gedit" ]]

  then

    sleep 1 && xdotool key "ctrl+s"

  else

    sleep 0.3 && xdotool key "alt+f" && sleep 0.1 && xdotool key s

fi

nwt(){
    find ~/ \
    ! -path "$HOME/.mozilla/*" \
    ! -path "$HOME/.config/libreoffice/*" \
    ! -path "$HOME/Public/*" \
    ! -path "$HOME/.local/share/Trash/*" \
    ! -path "$HOME/.config/google-chrome/*" \
    \( -name "*ods" \
    -o -name "*txt" \
    -o -name "*html" \
    -o -name "*odt" \
    -o -name ".bashrc" \
    -o -name ".bash_aliases" \
    -o -name "*\.sh" \
    -o -name "*\.mkd" \) \
    -type f  -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -r | head -1 | cut -f2- -d ' '
}

s=$(nwt)

sleep 2 && cp $(nwt) $HOME/Public/"${s##*/}-$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')"
```

- the script uses *xdotool* to simulate key presses and to detect the window title because gedit is different than the other editors in that it doesn't use the "legacy" <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.
- some of the code in `nwt` is from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/227909/248158).
- the use of `${s##*/}` is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664746).
- the *sleep*s may not be needed on a machine with good specs.

The resultant backup filename looks like this:

```
/home/dkb/Public/find-Carla-Schroder.mkd-20190829222116
```